# How does this code allocate memory and why does it fail to write to the allocated memory?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

Why does the code below compile successfully but fail to write memory other than address 0? (compiled in dev-cpp 6.3)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void alloc_arr(int **d_ptr);

int main() {
    int *ptr_i = NULL;
    alloc_arr(&ptr_i);
    
    if (ptr_i == NULL) {
        printf("ptr_i null");
        return 0;
    }
    
    printf("ptr_i %x value at 0 %d value at 1 %d",&ptr_i, ptr_i[0], ptr_i[1]);
    
    return 0;
}

void alloc_arr(int **d_ptr) {
    *d_ptr = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    if (d_ptr == NULL) {
        printf("cant allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    *d_ptr[0] = 15;
    *d_ptr[1] = 5;
}
```

I am expecting the code to allocate an array of memory from a function.

Comment: `if(d_ptr==NULL)` That should be `if(*d_ptr==NULL)`. If `d_ptr==NULL` already the allocation above is likely to crash

Comment: `%x` is not correct for printing out pointers. `%p` is.

Comment: I think, messing up operator precedence is not the same as a simple typo. It should not be closed as a typo.

Comment: Kindly don't merge so many statements in a single line.

Comment: what is your program output? what do you expect it to be?  Please, edit the question so we can make a diagnostic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to revisit [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

```c
*d_ptr[1]=5;
```

This is the same as `*(d_ptr[1])=5;` where `d_ptr[1]` is illegal as `d_ptr` only points to a single `int *`.

You want

```c
(*d_ptr)[1]=5;
```

There is also another error in your program:

```c
    if(d_ptr==NULL){printf("cant allocate memory");exit(1);}
```

If you come here, you have already dereference `d_ptr` causing undefined behaviour.
Also, according to the text you print, you want

```c
    if(*d_ptr==NULL){printf("cant allocate memory");exit(1);}
```

Finally, you print the address of your pointer variable, not where it points to and you also use wrong format specifier:

```c
 printf("ptr_i %x value at 0 %d value at 1 %d",&ptr_i, ptr_i[0], ptr_i[1]);
```

This should be:

```c
 printf("ptr_i %p value at 0 %d value at 1 %d", (void*)ptr_i, ptr_i[0], ptr_i[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong check:**

```
*d_ptr=(int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
if(d_ptr==NULL)
```

The check should be:

```
if (*d_ptr == NULL)
```

The code would trigger undefined behaviour if `d_ptr` was originally `NULL` and had been deferenced to store the return of `malloc()`.

---

**Unneeded cast**:

```
// *d_ptr=(int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));

   *d_ptr = malloc (sizeof *d_ptr * 2);
```

---

**Dereferencing out of bounds memory:**

```
*d_ptr[1]= 5
```

is parsed as:

```
*(d_ptr[1]) = 5;
```

But `d_ptr` only points to a single `int *`.

It should be:

```
(*d_ptr)[1] = 5;
```

---

**Indicate failure on failure:**

```
if (ptr_i == NULL) {
        printf("ptr_i null");
        return 0;
    }
```

Here, `return 0` is equivalent to `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`.

I suggest changing it to:

```
return EXIT_FAILURE; // or return 1;
```

---

**Wrong format specifier:**

```
printf("ptr_i %x value at 0 %d value at 1 %d",&ptr_i, ptr_i[0], ptr_i[1]);
```

The `%x` format specifier is not for printing out pointer addresses; `%p` is. And it expects a `void *`, which requires a cast like so:

```
printf("ptr_i %p value at 0 %d value at 1 %d", (void *) &ptr_i, ptr_i[0], ptr_i[1]);
```

Note that `&ptr_i` produces a pointer to `ptr_i`, you're looking for `ptr_i`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `if (d_ptr == NULL)` does not check for memory allocation success, you only test that the function argument is not a null pointer.  You should instead write

  ```
    if (*d_ptr == NULL)
  ```
- `*d_ptr[1] = 5;` does not initialize the second `int` in the allocated array, but rather attempts to dereference an `int *` at the address that follows that of `ptr_i` in `main`, which has undefined behavior.  Postfix operators bind stronger than prefix operators, so you should write

  ```
    (*d_ptr)[1] = 5;
  ```

  Note that `*d_ptr[0] = 15;` is confusing but not a problem because it is the same as `(*d_ptr)[0] = 15;` as well as `**d_ptr = 15;` or `d_ptr[0][0] = 15;` or even `0[*d_ptr] = 15;` or `*0[d_ptr] = 15;` etc.
- to print the value of a pointer in `printf`, you should use `%p` and cast the pointer to type `(void *)`.
- casting the return value of `malloc()` is not necessary in C.

Here is a modified version that is less error prone:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void alloc_arr(int **d_ptr);

int main(void) {
    int *ptr_i = NULL;
    alloc_arr(&ptr_i);
    
    if (ptr_i == NULL) {
        printf("ptr_i null\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("ptr_i %p value at 0 %d value at 1 %d\n",
           (void *)&ptr_i, ptr_i[0], ptr_i[1]);
    
    return 0;
}

void alloc_arr(int **d_ptr) {
    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(*ptr));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("cant allocate memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ptr[0] = 15;
    ptr[1] = 5;
    *d_ptr = ptr;
}
```

Note also that passing the address of the pointer is not necessary as you could simply return the pointer to the allocated block:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *alloc_arr(void);

int main(void) {
    int *ptr_i = alloc_arr();
    
    if (ptr_i == NULL) {
        printf("ptr_i is null\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("ptr_i %p value at 0 %d value at 1 %d\n",
           (void *)&ptr_i, ptr_i[0], ptr_i[1]);
    
    return 0;
}

int *alloc_arr(void) {
    int *ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof(*ptr));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ptr[0] = 15;
    ptr[1] = 5;
    return ptr;
}
```